# Windows Unable to complete the format

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I am using windows 7 in my machine.

My pendrive got corrupted while i was using it.

so i just removed the pen drive, then again when i inserted my pendrive
it was showing as some other unrecognized format..

so i just started the formatting the pen drive.after few minutes it gave an error.

**WINDOWS WAS UNABLE TO COMPLETE THE FORMAT**

What should i do for this?

Comment: Use Linex OS to format your pen drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do. Your pendrive is dead. I have lost almost 3 pendrives to this exact error. There are some recovery present in the website such :

[1. Sandisk's Recovery](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4985/~/data-recovery-for-memory-cards-and-flash-drives)

[2. HP USB Recovery Flash Drive](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-77449-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=4062&product=4057188)

[3. Kingston Media Recover](http://www.kingston.com/en/flash/media_recover)

The above link might help you out but chances are less. Although if you have a Transcend then you are unlucky as out of 3 two were transcend ( One was 16 GB :'( ). You can go to the website where you can download the Online recovery tool.

[4. JetFlash Online Recovery](http://www.transcend-info.com/products/online_recovery_2.asp)

I would be more than happy if you recover your pendrive. If you do please share the info with all of us.

*PS: Please do not remove the drive directly from next time and do not run high profile programs such as iso files and media files directly from the pendrive.*

Thank you.